# I want to delete an user photo after uploading

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project and I want to remove the previous photo on profile every time I upload another one.

I wrote the code but it doesn't delete the old file. I store the old photo in $oldFileName and after updating the photo i try to delete it with     Storage::delete($oldFilename);

HomeController.php:

```php
public function update(User $user)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $user->name = request('name');
    $user->phone = request('phone');
    $user->image = request('image');

    $oldFilename = $user->image;

    $this->storeImage($user);

    Storage::delete($oldFilename);

    $user->save();

    return redirect('user/account');
}

private function storeImage($user)
{
    if (request()->has('image')) {
        $user->image = $user->email . '.' . request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $user->image);

    }
}
```

config/filesystem.php:

```php
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I delete the old photo? Thank you

Comment: Do you get an error message when performing the delete?

Comment: Please can you add the code your `config/filesystem.php` to your question.

Comment: @theduck no, I get no error

Comment: @Rwd I added the config/filesystem.php. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

How to delete the file from public? you can use `File::delete('directory/file')`

In updating that would be like this. But you can scroll down to see other approach.

```
use File;

//* store image to public folder
public function storeImage($user)
{
    $file = $user->file;

    if (request()->has('image')){

        $filename = $user->image . '.' . request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //your directory for example
        $directory = "/img/";

        //saving to (/public/img/filename)
        $file->move(public_path($dir), $filename); 
    }
}

//* delete image from public folder
public function deleteCurrentImage(){

    //your directory for example
    $directory = "/img/";

    //your current image
    $filename = Auth::user()->image;

    //deleting (/public/img/filename)
    File::delete($filename.$file);
}

//* update your current image
public function updateImage(Request $r){

    //delete first the current image
    $this->deleteCurrentImage();

    //and store new image
    $this->storeImage($r->all(), Auth::user());
}
```

---

You can call now `updateImage` to update your current profile. If misunderstood your question please let me know.

Comment: Hi! I get this error when I use File::delete (Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\File::delete())

Comment: @TomaRareş add `use File;` at the top

Answer (score 0):

Use unlink($filename) function. // $filename is path to the file.